# Most rented movie by title PostgreSQL sample database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on getting the most popular movies rented per month by title.  So far I have been able to get the titles of the movies and the dates they were rented but the count column and date column are giving individual results.  Here is the query I am using.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT x.rental_date, x.title, x.count FROM(
SELECT ren.rental_date,fil.title,COUNT(ren.rental_id)
    FROM rental AS ren
    JOIN inventory AS inv ON ren.inventory_id = inv.inventory_id
    JOIN film AS fil ON inv.film_id = fil.film_id
    GROUP BY title, rental_date) AS x
    ORDER BY x.count,x.rental_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply aggregate by the year/month of the specific dates using [**`to_char`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/functions-formatting.html). Also, subquery is not necessary.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(ren.rental_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS rental_month, 
       fil.title,
       COUNT(ren.rental_id) AS rental_count
FROM rental AS ren 
JOIN inventory AS inv 
   ON ren.inventory_id = inv.inventory_id 
JOIN film AS fil 
   ON inv.film_id = fil.film_id 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ren.rental_date, 'YYYY-MM'),
         fil.title
ORDER BY rental_month,
         rental_count DESC
```

Consider also [**`date_part`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) for year and month extraction or [**`date_trunc`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) to normalize dates to first day of month to keep the timestamp type:

```sql
SELECT DATE_PART('year', ren.rental_date) AS rental_year, 
       DATE_PART('month', ren.rental_date) AS rental_month, 
       ...
```

```sql
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', ren.rental_date) AS rental_month, 
       ...
```